# How to calculate degree of confusion of an encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

I am programming an encryption-decryption model in python 3. I want to check its strength. I found 3 methods to check, they are:
1. Degree of diffusion
2. Degree of confusion
3. Integrity check

1. For diffusion, i found that we can calculate hamming distance then divide it by no of bits and multiply by 100. Is the correct procedure?
   2,3 For these two, can someone explain me the procedure on how to calculate this?

Also, is there any other method that can tell about the strength of the model?

Comment: Shivanjali let us know: are you programming a know cryptosystem? Or are you proposing a new one from scratch?

Comment: I am playing around with Speck crypto model in python